# Use an array declared inside an if condition elsewhere

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I declared an array depending upon a randomly generated number. Now i know we can't use an array generated inside an if block anywhere else but i heared there are ways like dynamic memory allocation & vectors etc?
any help on that?

```
    srand(time(0));
int num=rand() % 6 + 1;

if(num==1)
char word[6] = {'b','a','t','m','a','n'};

if(num==2)
char word[6]={'k','i','l','l','e','r'};

if(num==3)
char word[6]={'b','e','a','u','t','y'};
```

Comment: use a vector declared in your header file and then reassign it and use it wherever you like

Comment: This is C++. Why not `std::string`? Or at least `std::vector`? Remember an "array of characters" is just a "string". Maybe what you really need is `std::vector<std::string>` and then you can add the three (or N) entries. What you're trying to describe here is a look-up table, like `words[n]` is the word, where `n` is in the range 0 to 2.

Comment: For random numbers try and use good tools like [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) instead of junk like `rand(time(NULL))` which can have *huge, unintended consequences*.

Comment: Just a side note: `rand` and modulo do not produce good distributions. It's fine for just playing around a bit like here – if you have stronger requirements you get better results with `rand() * desired_max / RAND_MAX` – keep an eye on possible overflow, though (just to keep in mind for the future).

Comment: "any help on that?" isn't an acceptable problem statement. Your book surely teaches you about dynamic allocation. Do some research and see what you come up with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you show, you might use:

```
srand(time(0)); // Called only once, probably in main

char words[3][6] { // Possibly const // Possibly std::vector<std::string>
    {'b','a','t','m','a','n'},
    {'k','i','l','l','e','r'},
    {'b','e','a','u','t','y'}
};

int num = rand() % 3;
auto& word = words[num]; // char (&word)[6] = words[num];
```

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing it:

```
srand(time(0));
int num=rand() % 6 + 1;

vector <char> word;

if (num == 1)
    word = {'b','a','t','m','a','n'};

if (num == 2)
    word = {'k','i','l','l','e','r'};

if (num == 3)
    word = {'b','e','a','u','t','y'};
```

Or use an `std::string`

```
srand(time(0));
int num=rand() % 6 + 1;

string word;

if (num == 1)
    word = "batman";

if (num == 2)
    word = "killer";

if (num == 3)
    word = "beauty";
```

Comment: Using std::string is surely a better way here.

Comment: @LeontyevGeorgiy Yep, I was editing my answer to that as well

Comment: @LeontyevGeorgiy The question and it's title is pretty specific about wanting an array. We must presume the example of a character array is just as an example.

Comment: @LeontyevGeorgiy Depends on what one wants to do... For representation of text – absolutely. If storing arbitrary data, especially if it might contain null values, the vector is better choice – or the `std::array` of other answer, if we want to avoid dynamic allocations.

Comment: @Aconcagua Well, maybe. Still, if such a problem has arisen, I doubt that this is anything more than a school task. These don't have "arbitrary data" requirements usually, at least, on a beginner level. If the TC wasn't a beginner, such question would not be asked at all.

Answer (score 3):

```
srand(time(0));
int num=rand() % 6 + 1;

std::array <char, 6> word;

if (num == 1)
    word = {'b','a','t','m','a','n'};
else if (num == 2)
    word = {'k','i','l','l','e','r'};
else if (num == 3)
    word = {'b','e','a','u','t','y'};
```